# how to retrieve value from entity framework core calling stored procedure with parameter invoke firstordefault method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-core

I am converting from .Net WebApi to .Net Core API.

I want the first value from procedure calling entity framework core to invoke `FirstOrDefault()`

Below is my proc code:

```
CREATE procedure sp_employee
@DelReqId int  
AS  
Begin  
    Select isnull(ApproverCode,'') ApproverCode from employee where Del_ReqId=@DelReqId  
End
```

C# code:

```
public string GetApproverId(int ReqId)
    {
        string result = "";
        
            //int result = ctx.CDS_CheckForSaveAfterValidationFalse(Appid, RoleId);
            var ReqIdParam = new SqlParameter("@DelReqId", ReqId);
        


        result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("exec LMS.CDS_GetApproverSAPIDOnReqId @DelReqId", ReqIdParam).ToString();


        return result;
    }
```

I need replace `ToStiring()` with `FirstOrDefault()`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your entity framework's  version that you are use it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use  db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw if you need to get some result from DB.

You will have to create a special class for sp result

```
public class ApproverSpResult
{
 public string ApproverCode {get; set;}
}
```

Then add this class to the dbcontext

```
  public virtual DbSet<ApproverSpResult> ApproverSpResults { get; set; }

   //and OnModelCreating

   modelBuilder.Entity<ApproverSpResult>(e =>
            {
                e.HasNoKey();
            });
```

Only after this you can get your result from SP

```
public string GetApproverCode(int ReqId)
    {
      var ReqIdParam = new SqlParameter("@DelReqId", ReqId);

      var approverSpResult= db.ApproverSpResults.ExecuteSqlRaw("exec 
                 LMS.CDS_GetApproverSAPIDOnReqId @DelReqId", ReqIdParam)
              .ToList()
             .FirstOrDefault();
   
 if(approverSpResult!=null) return approverSpResult.ApproverCode;
 
   return null;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for reply, i did same, but i'm getting error at below code

Comment: var approverSpResult = db.ApproverSpResults.ExecuteSqlRaw("exec LMS.CDS_GetApproverSAPIDOnReqId @DelReqId", ReqIdParam).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1929 'DbSet<ApproverSpResult>' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteSqlRaw' and the best extension method overload 'RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRaw(DatabaseFacade, string, params object[])' requires a receiver of type 'DatabaseFacade

Comment: I see the name sp_employee. What is the real stored procedure?

Comment: I updated my answer. Instead of  ".FirstOrDefault" try to  use  .ToList().FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Hi now it's working. with your updated answer. thanks you.